# Is it possible to use spark to process complex entities with complex dependencies?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, distributed-computing

Consider a scenario (objects and dependencies are `Scala` classes):

There is a set of dependencies which themselves require significant amount of data to be instantiated (data coming from a database).
There is a set of objects with complex nested hierarchy which store references to those dependencies.

The current workflow consist of:

1. Loading the dependencies data from a database and instantiating them
   (in a pretty complex way with interdependencies).
2. Loading object
   data from the database and instantiating objects using previously
   loaded dependencies.
3. Running operations on a list of objects like:

   ```
   a. Search with a complex predicate
   b. Transform
   c. Filter
   d. Save to the database
   e. Reload from the database
   ```

We  are considering running these operations on multiple machines. One of the options is to use `Spark`, but it is not clear how to properly support data serialization and distribute/update the dependencies.

Even if we are able to separate the logic in the objects from the data (making objects easily serializable) the functions we want to run over the objects will still rely on the complex dependencies mentioned above.

Additionally, at least at the moment, we don't have plans to use any operations requiring shuffling of the data between machines and all we need is basically sharding.

Does `Spark` look like a good fit for such scenario?

- If yes, how to handle the complex dependencies?
- If no, would appreciate any pointers to alternative systems that can handle the workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand enough what you mean by "complex interdependencies" but it seems that if you only need sharding you won't really get much from spark - just run multiple whatever you have an use a queue to synchronize the work and distribute to each copy the shard it needs to work on.

We did something similar converting a pySpark jot to a Kubernetes setup where the queue holds the list of ids and then we have multiple pods (we control the scale via kubectl) that read from that queue and got much better performance and simpler solution - see https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/coarse-parallel-processing-work-queue/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! By complex interdependencies I mean that instantiating them is a pretty complex piece of logic, requiring loading many parts from the database, inflating and properly wiring different pieces. We've considered Kubernetes (even built a prototype), but it will require work from our side to properly synchronize the pods, handle the failures, manage task priorities and so on. All doable, but spark has this built-in, so we want to better understand the cost of onboarding to spark vs building a more narrow in-house solution.

Comment: spark is not built for controlling which part of the logic will run on which node - you need to build everything as if it will fit inside a single machine and then let spark worry about making that work in a distributed manner. if you need more refined control take a look at heron or in-memory data grids

Comment: yeah, but in order to distribute the work spark needs my data to be serializable. And essentially each object in the RDD has a references to the dependencies, which will result in very complex serialization. If I decouple the data from the logic and only put the data in the RDD, the logic (for example function passed to map or filter) still relies on the dependencies. Does this imply each call to RDD.map(f)/filter(f)/whatever(f) will result in full serialization of f including the dependencies I've mentioned above? Essentially it will be pretty costly?

Comment: mostly you want to use datasets (or dataframes) and not RDDs since spark optimizes them better. Still, any udfs you'd define will need to be serialized and you should strive to define your dependencies as datasets as well and then achieve as much as possible as sql-like (join, unions etc.) operations

Comment: I think another option is to make the dependencies a broadcast variable and use it in the udfs.

Comment: @andrew it is an option technically. But spark doesn't know how to optimize UDFs so if possible they should be avoided (there are a few higher order functions in the latest releases that are also usable)

Comment: To sum, the more of your process you can express in pure spark terms the better the fit and vice versa